# Add trycatch inside method code failing with JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames option

Tags: jvm, java-bytecode-asm

I am writing a Java agent which is supposed to be attached
to a running JVM. On that running JVM, there is a class already loaded and agent wants to instrument a method of that class.

The agent uses the ASM framework to add a `try`/`catch` block in the method content which is to be instrumented.

Below is the code I have written to add the `try`/`catch` block:

```
public void visitCode() {
  if (mMethodName.equals("test")) {       
    mv.visitLabel(startFinally);      
    super.visitCode();
  }  
}
public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals) {
   Label endFinally = new Label();
   mv.visitTryCatchBlock(startFinally,endFinally,endFinally,
    "java/lang/Exception");
   mv.visitLabel(endFinally);
   mv.visitVarInsn(ASTORE, 1);
   mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);
   mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Exception",
    "printStackTrace", "()V"););
}
```

I am using `ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES` in `ClassWriter`, but I'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames option
  at com.bea.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.bea.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitJumpInsn(Unknown Source)
  at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I have trouble trying to understand the relevance of method exit points here. Since there is exactly one method entry point, you are adding exactly one `try` block in the sole `onMethodEnter()` invocation. Why do you want to add more than one `catch` block? How are these `catch` blocks associated with the method exit instead of the `try` block?

Comment: I want to add only one catch block but that i want to add in the end of method code. And that catch block i am doing when onMEthodExit(int opcode) is called. Now this onMethodExit() will be called many times and I don't know when that call is the last call . so my implementation of onMethodExit() adds catch block in the middle of method when return is there or exception is being thrown.

Comment: So why don’t you use `visitEnd()` instead?

Comment: Did that, it's working now.

Comment: I saw it getting compiled and thought that it is working but it is giving error JSR/RET are not supported in computeFrame option. Any suggestions?

Comment: `jsr` and `ret` are not allowed in class files with a version above `50`. If you want to instrument such classes, you’ll have to find a different way of expressing your intent. If you are going to instrument classes with a version below `50`, `StackMapTable`s are not supported, so you don’t need to specify the `COMPUTE_FRAMES` option to ASM but can use `jsr` and `ret`. If the class file is *exactly* `50`, things get more complicated. In general, not using `jsr` and `ret`, adhering to the de-facto standard of this version, is the best option.

Comment: Updated the question as could not put that in comment.

Comment: I don’t see how this changes what I already told you. `jsr` and `ret` are not allowed in class files with version `51`. If you catch the associated exception you may continue to get the class bytes and even be able to decompile it. Nobody says that the decompiler has to care about the invalidity of the presence of `jsr` and `ret` nor does it have to care about the `StackMapTable` that hasn’t been computed. But trying to load these bytes as a class into the JVM is a different thing though.

Comment: So, what should I do in this case? appreciate your help! Can we chat?

Comment: Just to be sure: you acknowledge that your code is utilizing `jsr` and `ret`? Then it all boils down to “*How can I achieve the same without these two instructions*?”. In this case, you should replace your question with an appropriate new one, showing everything you’re doing, including a description of the goal(s), allowing us to suggest alternatives. Do either, edit your question or delete it and create a new one…

Comment: Edited the question completely. Please let me know if any details is missing.

Comment: That code doesn’t produce `jsr` or `ret` instructions. Maybe they are already in the source class, but then it can’t have version `51`. Are you changing the version number during the transformation? If the class file has a lower version number, just removing the `COMPUTE_FRAME` option (replace it with `COMPUTE_MAXS`) should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Now I am not getting JSR/RET error as I found that there was another class which was also getting instrumented and that was compiled in version 49. But I am still using COMPUTE_FRAMES as I don't want to compute frames because of my limited knowledge of ASM. And I am getting another exception which is ClassNotFoundException in getCommonSuperClass method of ClassWriter. I am going to override this method and do the class loading . Hopefully it should work.

Comment: It seems you missed the point. If the class version is `49`, you can omit `COMPUTE_FRAMES`, because you don’t need to compute them. These frames are a new feature of version `50`. Older versions don’t know them and hence don’t require them. You only have to care to keep the older version number for the transformed class.

Comment: So, If I use COMPUTE_MAXS, then how will I calculate Frames as I am adding trycatch? Adding trying catch must be adding the frames.